# jQuery scroll left and fadeIn at the same time

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have the following code and its working great to scroll my divs left. But I need them to both scroll left and fade in as they are scrolling to the left.

How can I do this?

```
$('div#line1').delay(1000).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1500);
$('div#line2').delay(2000).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1500);
$('div#line3').delay(3000).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1500);
```

The CSS for these is set to display:none

```
#line1,
#line2,
#line3{
display: none;
}
```

Comment: `.fadeIn(1000)` - Have you tried adding that to your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take this sort of approach, expanding on Brad M's answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/Gqttc/

Given this HTML:

```
<div id="clickme">Click here</div>
<div id="lines">
    <div id="line1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x40" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="line2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x40" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="line3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x40" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and this CSS:

```
#lines div {
    opacity:0;
    margin-left:-400px
}
```

you can take this approach with your jQuery:

```
// get your lines into an array
var lines = $("#lines div");
// set a counter
var currAnim = 0;

// this method will animate a line
var fadeMoveIn = function (line) {
    $(line).animate({
        opacity: 1,
        marginLeft: 10
    }, {
        queue: true,
        duration: 1000,
        complete: function () {
            // when this line's animation is done
            // trigger the next in the queue
            startQueue();
        }
    });
};

// this function will fire off your animations one by one
var startQueue = function () {
    // increment the queue and send that line to be animated
    fadeMoveIn(lines[currAnim++]);
};

$("#clickme").click(function () {
    startQueue();
});
```

Hope that gives you some ideas on ways you can manage this! Brad's method is a good start, but it will animate all your divs simultaneously, which is not quite the effect I think you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the .animate() method. Something like the following

```
$(divs).animate({
     width: 100,
     opacity: 100
});
```

Make sure the divs originally have an opacity of 0%, and you'll need to experiment with the correct widths.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#div1").click(function() {
     $('#div1').animate({"left": -200, "opacity": "toggle" }, "slow");
});
```

for the example I bound this to the click event but you can take the function and use as you need. Also, if you give all of the divs a common class you can move them all at once:

```
 $('.moveMe').animate({"left": -200, "opacity": "toggle" }, "slow");
```

Here's a JSFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/BCeeC/19/)

Edit: You could also use `toggle` to slide the div to the left based on it's width:

```
$('#div1').animate({"width": toggle, "opacity": "toggle" }, "slow");
```